# Framework for combining components

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a framework, or a nice way of implementing a way combining various components, similar to an electronics kit. This is so that it can be wired together using xml (e.g. Spring). I want the users to be able to string together different components without having to worry about Java.

The set up I'm thinking of would have something like the following:

```
public interface Input<T> {
    public T getValue();
}

public interface Output<T> {
    public void setValue(T value);
}

public class Wire<T> implements Input<T>, Output<T> {
    private T value;
    public T getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(T value) { this.value = value ; };
}
```

And then components would be something like

```
public interface Component {
    public void evaluate(); 
}
public class Multiplier implements Component {
    private Input<Double> inA;
    private Input<Double> inB;
    private Output<Double> out;

    public Multiplier(Input<Double> inA, Input<Double> inB, Output<Double> out) {
        this.inA = inA;
        this.inB = inB;
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void evaluate() {
        out.setValue(inA.getValue() * inB.getValue());
    }
}

main() {
    Wire inA = new Wire();
    Wire squareOut = new Wire();

    Component squarer = new Multiplier(inA, inA, output)
}
```

So you could tie outputs of one component into the input of another. I've toyed with the idea of the Wires knowing about what outputs they're connected to, so that they can call evaluate on their components... but I think it might be easier to keep a separate "clock" so that circular dependencies can be controlled.

It's not hard to implement, I'd just rather use a public library if there is one already out there. I've struggled to find one.

Any advice about implementing something similar, or what to do instead would be really helpful.

Comment: `but I think it might be easier to keep a separate "clock"` What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Answer (score -1):

**You are talking about Dependency Injection Framework.**

Look at Spring, Google Guice or PicoContainer.

Comment: `So you could tie outputs of one component into the input of another`. There's a question hidden here somewhere and using a DI container does not answer this question.